# Windows Form OnClosing Stopping a Thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am new to C# and I am having a problem. I have a Form that runs a thread which receives input from a serial port. However when the window is closed the thread keeps running. I tried overriding `virtual void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)` but the MessageBox keeps popping up which means the thread is still running. What am I doing wrong? Which is the best lifecycle method to override to do cleanup before the window is closed?

**DisplayForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace project
{
    public partial class DisplayForm : Form
    {
        private Thread readThread;
        private SerialPort port;
        private bool running;

        public DisplayForm(String portName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            port = new SerialPort(portName);
            port.Open();

            readThread = new Thread(Read);
            running = true;
            readThread.Start();
        }

        public void Read()
        {
            while (running)
            {
                try
                {
                    string message = port.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write(message);
                    MessageBox.Show(message);
                }
                catch (TimeoutException)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            running = false;
            readThread.Join();
            port.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "that doesn't seem to work" ... why not? What happens? What do you see in the debugger?

Comment: Nothing in the debugger. MessageBoxes keep popping up which means the thread is still running

Comment: Could it be a backlog of messages?  What if you remove the MessageBox and watch the console instead?

Comment: Console messages keep happening as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Abort()` and not `Join()`.

```
protected virtual void OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) 
{ 
    running = false; 
    readThread.Abort();
    port.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OnClosing or OnClosed event call try to see any child thread running and abort them all...in your code first call port.close and then runThread which you already have access to it in Oncl